# where to update database details in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

i would like to update the database details where the website has been developed using zend framework. I dont know where I need to update the db details as new to the framework.

And also need help on what are the changes to be made when we move all files from centralised server to a local server like a intranet websource.

Answer (score 0):

DB details are often provided in the application.ini config file : "resources.db.params.< a param >", for instance : resources.db.params.dbname = "mydatabase"
[edit] This config file can be found in application/configs/ folder

But it could be provided anywhere, depending on the developper tastes and willings to follow the best practices...
You should perform a massive search with keyword "dbname" and you'll find it !

Comment: This file would be in `application/configs/` if I'm not mistaken

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really fuzzy. If you are using ZF 1.12:

You can set your database configuration in your application.ini like this:

```
resources.db.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = "foo"
resources.db.params.password = "secret"
resources.db.params.dbname = "bar"
```

Furthermore, you have the option to set an environment variable to production / development and use different configurations.

```
[production : bootstrap]
    resources.db.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
    resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
    resources.db.params.username = "foo"
    resources.db.params.password = "secret"
    resources.db.params.dbname = "bar"

[development : bootstrap]
    resources.db.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
    resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
    resources.db.params.username = "foo"
    resources.db.params.password = "another_secret"
    resources.db.params.dbname = "bar"
```